# how to open website link or folder location stored in variable using start command in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that takes input as website name or folder location as input as opens site in browser or location in windowsexplorer respectively.

But whenever it runs, it just opens another command prompt. Please help.
Here's the code:

```
@echo off
:up
echo 1. Windows Explorer
echo 2. Website
echo 3. Exit
set /p ch=Enter choice for app to open:
if %ch%==1 (
    set /p pth=Enter full path of folder:
    start "%pth%"
    pause
    goto up
)
if %ch%==2 (
    set /p site=Enter name of website:
    start "%site%"
    pause
    goto up
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution
Just had to add double quotes after start as I'm using double quotes to specify the address
Like this:

```
start "" "%site%"
```